# how to access object passed through named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails newb and have what seems to be a trivial/fundamental rails problem.

I have a link in which I am trying to pass information about the object:

```
<% for author in @book.authors %>
  <%= link_to "compute", special_book_path(author) %>
```

How can I access the "author" object (that was passed through the special named route) in the controller?

I tried:

```
@author = @book.authors.find(params[:author])
```

but got a "Couldn't find Author without an ID" error.

Edit: Solution

```
special_book_path(author_id: author.id)
```

Controller

```
params[:author_id]
```

Comment: i wonder how you set @book in your controller code if the route has no info on book. is there only a single special book?

Comment: The code above is just an illustration because the actual code is more complex and harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <%= link_to "compute", special_book_path(author: author) %>
```

This would pass only the id of the author not the author object. And you cannot pass objects in the route.

In the controller you can access the passed argument as params[:author]

```
  @author = @book.authors.find(params[:author])
```

Answer (score 2):

when you set up the named route, you set a request parameter name, usually `:id`, when you use `special_book_path(author)`, the value of this param is set to `author.to_param` which is by default `author.send(author.class.primary_key)` which is normally `author.id`, so probably simply

```
@author = Author.find(params[:id])
```

will work